# I have a simple javascript issue that takes name input/ output the name with phrase

Tags: javascript, forms

I don't think that my JavaScript function is working correctly to output the name.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en-US">
<head>
<meta charset = "UTF-8">
<title>textbox.html</title>
<script type = "text/javascript">
//text box
function sayHi()
{
 var txtName = document.getElementByID("txtName") ;
 var txtOutput = document.getElementByID("txtOutput") ;
 var name = txtName.value ;
 txtOutput.value = "Hi there, " +  name +  "!" ;
}
//end HI
</script>
<link rel = "stylesheet"
  type= "text/css"
  href = "textBoxes.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Text Box Input and Output</h1>
<form action = "">
<fieldset>
    <label>Type your name</label>
    <input type = "text"
           id = "txtName" />
    <input type = "button"
           value = "click me"
             onclick = "sayHi ()" />
    <input type = "text"
           id = "txtOutput" />
  </fieldset>
 </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

/*What am I doing wrong because once I input the name and click me button doesn't give any output. I really think my function is not setup correctly. */

Comment: There is a typo on `getElementByID()` that should instead be `getElementById()`. I think that will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's **getElementById** and not **getElementByID**.
the last *d* should not be capital.

Comment: Please do not answer "Simple typographical error" questions. They should be closed instead because they do not add anything usefull to the website for future users.

Answer (score 0):

try `document.getElementById`, not `document.getElementByID` (no upper case ID)

Comment: Please do not answer "Simple typographical error" questions. They should be closed instead because they do not add anything usefull to the website for future users.

Answer (score 0):

Try it .

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang = "en-US">
    <head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>textbox.html</title>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
    //text box
    function sayHi()
    {
        var txtName     = document.getElementById("txtName") ;
        var txtOutput   = document.getElementById("txtOutput") ;
        var name        = txtName.value ;
        txtOutput.value = "Hi there, " +  name +  "!" ;
    }
    //end HI
    </script>
    <link rel = "stylesheet"
      type= "text/css"
      href = "textBoxes.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Text Box Input and Output</h1>
    <form action = "">
    <fieldset>
        <label>Type your name</label>
        <input type = "text"
               id = "txtName" />
        <input type = "button"
               value = "click me"
                 onclick = "sayHi()" />
        <input type = "text"
               id = "txtOutput" />
      </fieldset>
     </form>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few corrections:

- The getElementByID is supposed to be getElementById.
- You could alternatively use oninput instead of onclick, but it will show as soon as you input. Try removing the button; it's much quicker.
- For txtOutput, try using output instead of input, unless you want to type in the output itself.

Here's a corrected version:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en-US">
<head>
<meta charset = "UTF-8">
<title>textbox.html</title>
<script type = "text/javascript">
//text box
function sayHi()
{
 var txtName = document.getElementById("txtName") ;
 var txtOutput = document.getElementById("txtOutput") ;
 var name = txtName.value ;
 txtOutput.value = "Hi there, " +  name +  "!" ;
}
//end HI
</script>
<link rel = "stylesheet"
  type= "text/css"
  href = "textBoxes.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Text Box Input and Output</h1>
<form action = "">
<fieldset>
    <label>Type your name</label>
    <input type = "text"
           id = "txtName"
           oninput = "sayHi()" />
    <output type = "text"
           id = "txtOutput" />
  </fieldset>
 </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank You very much. This has helped me a lot. Something very simple that I missed.